# What can Devise do that Authlogic can't?

Tags: devise, authlogic

The rails community seems to be leaving Authlogic in favor of Devise.  I have been using Authlogic for over a year and would like to know what the reasons are.  Is it just marketing, or is there a good reason for this?  I have used Devise and prefer Authlogic at this point, but if there is a good reason to make the switch I certainly would.

I have read quite a bit on Devise but I don't see where the excitement comes from.  The main reason I like the idea of Devise is because of the community support - as of this writing stackoverflow has 605 questions for Authlogic and 2580 for Devise.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Devise is solid, has a lot of features and has huge community support.
2. Devise has integrations with and/or is used by lots of other important projects -- such as OmniAuth or ActiveAdmin.
3. [JOSE VALIM](https://github.com/josevalim)!

I mean seriously, how many people do you know have over 1500 github followers? He's a core rails contributor, basically wrote devise, and is one of the most influential people in the ruby and rails communities.

Comment: Your real name wouldn't happen to be Jose, would it?  ;)